# How to run the PHP code in eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse

I have Eclipse editor, and i need to run my php web application. So which is the better way to run, either Run As---> PHP Script or Run As---> PHP web page. Presently for both I am getting the notification error.
Please help me in this....

Answer (score 2):

That is not true at all. You can run php scripts from the command line using "php scriptname.php "

Comment: This may require a specific setup of PHP, but it's definetely posible. If you don't have php or php.exe binary, look for php-cgi instead.

Answer (score 1):

Mh don't think that you can just run it... try it with xampp and put the project folder in the htdocs folder of xampp for example

Comment: Ya i have xampp and kept the project folder in the htdocs only but its giving the message in browser window as  "Notice notice C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\MyProject"   and in DEBUG window  "<terminated, exit value: 0>
E:\Editor\eclipse\plugins\org.zend.php.debug.debugger.win32.x86_5.3.18.v20100603\resources\php5\php-cgi.exe" ..... What exactly it is saying.

Comment: I dont know this error msg.
Are you sure that you configured Xampp correctly!?

Comment: I haven't changed any thing in that configuration file. What to configure there..?

Comment: I dont know exactly where the problem is.. but maybe this helps you:
http://www.mattbearman.co.uk/2010/05/18/how-to-install-zend-framework-with-xampp/

Answer (score 0):

i've never used run as php script, always as run as web page then give the url that corresponds to that page, or if you need to debug a page that give the url that will then call the file that you want to debug

Answer (score 0):

You can't really run your PHP scripts as programs, you need to setup a [local] server with PHP. After doing so, all you will have to do to run the code would be to open the corresponding URL in the browser. If you install [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/de/xampp.html) which is the most common choice for local development, you will be able to access your files through the `localhost` URL.

Comment: Actually, you can. Of course if you intend to display the result in a web browser, it's not your best option ...